# How to convert numbers to buttlet on blur

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

I require to use the input type as `tel`, but i should turn this as bullet with some seconds. i can use the `text-security` but which is not compatible for all browsers.

so, I decide to use some sepcial fonts, which inputs numbers as bullets. or turning values as bullet using html code.

any one show me the correct way to implement this? where can i get the free bullet font for turn numbers as bullet?

my try would be :

```
$('input:tel').on('focusin', function(){

    $(this).css({"font-family":"arial"});

});
//after 4 seconds..
$('input:tel').on('focusout', function(){

    $(this).css({"font-family":"times"}); //turn to bullet

})
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try to create a working example link of your problem and state clrearly what is not working.

Comment: It´s impossible to understand what you want.